# Why does the Express' default error handler catch error when emitting from Readable stream?

Tags: node.js, express, stream, streaming

I installed a boilerplate Express app using the command line `express stream_test`. I replaced the default `/routes/index.js` with:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ReadFile = require('./readFile.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var readFile = ReadFile();
  readFile
  .on('data', function(data) {
    res.write(data);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    res.end();
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

`readFile.js` is just a simple wrapper for `fs.createReadStream`:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');

function ReadFile(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof ReadFile)) {
    return new ReadFile(options);
  }
  Readable.call(this);

  options = options || {};

  var self = this;

  fs.createReadStream('pride_and_prejudice.txt')
  .on('data', function(data) {
    self.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', function(end) {
    self.push(null);
  });

}

util.inherits(ReadFile, Readable);
ReadFile.prototype._read = function _readGetDeals() {};

module.exports = ReadFile;
```

That works totally fine. It outputs the contents of `pride_and_prejudice.txt` to the screen when calling the route.

But let's say some requirements are not met and I want to throw an error before streaming the data:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');

function ReadFile(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof ReadFile)) {
    return new ReadFile(options);
  }
  Readable.call(this);

  options = options || {};

  var self = this;

  if (!options.okay) {
    return self.emit('error', new Error('Forced crash'));
  }

  fs.createReadStream('pride_and_prejudice.txt')
  .on('data', function(data) {
    self.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', function(end) {
    self.push(null);
  });

}
```

That throws an error `Forced crash.` when `options.okay` is `false`. I expect to catch the error in my `index.js` route while listening on the `error`. But the handler never executes. To my very surprise the default error handler in `app.js` is catching the error:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
```

**This is driving me nuts. How does the error end up there? Why isn't the event listener catching it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is the 'error' event is emitted even before the stream object finished being created. As a result node doesn't find the 'error' listener that you attached since it's not yet created and throws it as `Unhandled 'error' event`.

One solution would be delay the event emit using `setImmediate`. Then it'll create the stream object and bind the error listeners first before emitting the error :

```
 if (!options.okay) {
    setImmediate(function(){ 
      self.emit('error', new Error('Forced crash')); 
    });
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) When you emit `error` the ReadFile returns nothing, as well as the nearest trap for errors outside of the router module, then after the call ReadFile she called.

2) You can use `try-catch`:

```
try {
  var readFile = ReadFile();
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

3) Or use callback for error:

```
function ReadFile(options, errorCallback) {
  /**...**/
  if (!options.okay) {
    errorCallback( new Error('Forced crash') );
    return;
  }
  /**...**/ 
}
```